# How do I get the Key of Flame?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I can't figure out how to get the key from the Jewelled Crown of Anton quest. There are 4 braziers to activate.

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jeweled_Crown_of_Anton